# No print service found error message

Tags: java, printing, ubuntu-12.04

I started to create a simple Java application to print "Hello World" with the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class HelloWorldPrinter implements Printable, ActionListener { 

public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now we perform our rendering */
    g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setPrintable(this);
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
     if (ok) {
         try {
              job.print();
         } catch (PrinterException ex) {
          /* The job did not successfully complete */
         }
     }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
    });
    JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
    printButton.addActionListener(new HelloWorldPrinter());
    f.add("Center", printButton);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

This doesn't work, I get a "No print service found" alert message.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and the Java version is 1.7.0_25.

How can I get rid of this alert?

Answer (score 9):

Install cups-pdf, it will install a virtual printer which creates PDF files:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got printing to PDFs working on Arch Linux:

1. `sudo pacman -S cups-pdf`
2. `sudo systemctl enable org.cups.cupsd.service`
3. `sudo systemctl start org.cups.cupsd.service`
4. Add printer "Generic CUPS-PDF" with `sudo system-config-printer`, see screenshot below
5. Created PDFs are in `/var/spool/cups-pdf/$USER`
6. To change the output directory, edit the `Out` configuration key in `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`

[image: Screenshot of system-config-printer]

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS i have used PDFWriter :

1. You can get the installer from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfwriterformac/)

2. After installing the package, go back and click on it -> Show Package Contents.
3. From there uncompress Archive.pax.gz and copy PDFwriter.ppd file into /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources. You may need to create the last 3 folders. Also, if you don't find the Library folder, it is hidden by default, so just press shift+command+"."
4. Now go to the Printers dialog in Settings and add the printer.